# Silverlight: Unit Testing, recommended framework for SL4?

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, silverlight-4.0, nunit, moq

I am looking for some help with regards to SL4 and unit testing.

Is there a standard unit testing framework that exists? developed by microsoft?

I have found a number of ports for nunit and microsoft .net tests...

I would really appreciate any info with regards which framework to use.

While i am on it, a moq toolkit also exists for silverlight - any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) includes a unit testing framework which is pretty powerful.

Also, you should consider the [Microsoft Test Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385901.aspx) and its framework (if your development environment has access to it), as it contains great UI Test automation options that integrate with Silverlight as well as Web, WPF, and Win.Forms.

Answer (score 1):

If you access to Visual Studio Feature Pack 2, you can play with the Coded UI framework for Automated Unit Test. See my video [here](http://michaelcrump.net/archive/2010/12/11/silverlight-4-ndash-coded-ui-framework-video-tutorial.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I have had great success with NUnit and Moq with Silverlight.  I like that with NUnit, the tests run outside the plug-in sandbox, so they run quickly and on CI machines.

Comment: Could you help me with that ? I can not figure it out how to run NUnit + Moq + SL in one package. Do you have any tutorial ? Links ?

Comment: @Jasper Hmmm.  It has been a long time since I did it.  You need the NUnit libraries built for Silverlight(http://code.google.com/p/nunit-silverlight/) as well as the Moq built for Silverlight (http://code.google.com/p/moq/downloads/list).  I also used TestDriven.net to run the tests.  Good luck!